# Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that A is non-meagre

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that A is non-meagre and has the barie property.

Show there exists real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ < $y$ and ($x$,$y$) \ $A$ is meagre.

I know that since $A$ has the barie property there exists an open set $U$, such that the symmetric difference $A\Delta U$ is meagre. Since A is a subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ and has the barie property would this imply that $A$ is not $\mathbb{R}$. Could I just choose two points in outside of $A$?

Comment: Hint: if $U$ is not empty then it contains an open interval.

Comment: (It's spelled "Baire".)

Comment: I think I see it. Since A has the Baire property, there exist some open set such that AΔU is meagre. So I should just choose two points in U. Then that will be a subset of the symmertic difference between A and U. And a subset of a meagre set is meagre.

Comment: Not any two poitns in $U$, two points in an interval contained in $U$.

Comment: I see, I was thinking erroneously that $U$ must be a single interval. A small follow up question, does it matter where $U$ is? Could it be contained in $A$ ?